# How to use libuv async handles in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: c, thread-safety, libuv

`uv_async_send` is thread-safe, but [`uv_async_init`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/async.html?highlight=uv_async_init) is not. If I use `uv_async_init` to create an async handle in the loop’s thread, I may call `uv_async_send` many times, but its callback will only be called once. I need the callback to be called the same number of times as I call `uv_async_send`.

But it's not safe when I create an async handle for each callback in another thread. So, how can I use libuv async handles in a thread-safe manner?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a single async handle in the loop's thread.
2. Implement a thread-safe queue. (libuv doesn't expose one in its API, but it does expose primitives useful for creating one, e.g. `uv_mutex_t`)
3. The other threads put an item in the thread-safe call and then immediately call `uv_async_send`.
4. The async callback removes all pending items from the queue and processes them.

Answer (score -1):

> uv_async_init is not thread safe … it's not safe when i create async handle for each callback in other thread … i can creat a async handle in loop's thread

It appears you misunderstand the term *thread safe*. It does not mean that you may not call `uv_async_init()` from a thread other than the loop thread. It just means that you may not call it from multiple threads in parallel (without interlocking).

Comment: you are wrong，uv_async_init function need libuv's loop handle of parameter(add event to loop)，what always running in loop thread.  so, can call this func from other thread?

Comment: I only tried to clarify the general meaning of _thread safe_. I don't understand what you mean by "libuv's loop handle … what always running in loop thread" - how can a _handle_ be _running_?

Comment: sorry，i did not explain clearly。i mean，in libuv loop‘s thread，it operating loop's hanle for run && add && close libuv’s events。the uv_async_init func add a async event in loop thread by loop’s hanlde。so ，it’s unsafe call  uv_async_init out of loop‘s thread。

Comment: I agree this answer is incorrect. `uv_async_init` modifies the `uv_loop_t` data structures which are not thread-safe, so it is unsafe to call it from any thread other than the main loop thread (i.e. the thread that owns that particular `uv_loop_t`). `uv_async_send` by contrast is explicitly documented to be safe to call from other threads. So that's what "uv_async_init is not thread-safe" means. Saghul (one of the libuv developers) confirms it [here](https://groups.google.com/g/libuv/c/Ef0-NblPVis/m/xJUq4Kf0qnkJ)